# Android AppSearch Multi Word Tokens

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appsearch

I am trying to integrate Android [AppSearch](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/search/appsearch) and so far so good. However, I can't work out how to create multi-word tokens. Currently, any text added to a document is converted to tokens using non-alphanumeric characters. So, "apple tree" is converted into the tokens "apple" and "tree". However, certain terms need to be 1 token, so that a search for "tree" does not return a result (we are using INDEXING_TYPE_PREFIXES). I have tried setting the value as ""apple tree"", but this has no effect and a result is still returned for the search term "tree":

```
val searchManager = SearchManager(baseContext)
val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
val note = Note(id = id, text = "\"apple tree\"")
val result = searchManager.addNote(note)
```

**Note.kt**

```
@Document
data class Note(
    /** Namespace for Note */
    @Document.Namespace
    val namespace: String = "user",

    /** Id for Note */
    @Document.Id
    val id: String,

    /** Field for text that that user inputs */
    @Document.StringProperty(
        indexingType = AppSearchSchema.StringPropertyConfig.INDEXING_TYPE_PREFIXES
    )
    val text: String
)
```

Is there anyway to enable AppSearch to create multi-word tokens?